# Why C# compilation symbol is not suggested to have indent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the example code:

[image]

**Why not like the following? Thanks!**

[image]

Comment: This question is wrong. `#if` *can* be indented, and it is not a macro.

Comment: @harold suggestion taken.

Comment: OK, but it still applies that it can be indented. It is just put on the left by default by auto-formatting, that is all.

Comment: @harold yes, but many example I read are using the indent from image 1 not image 2, just want to know the reason.

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe this is because these will be handled by the pre-processor, so to give people a hint that these will be evaluated *before* anything is sent to the compiler.

Comment: I expect it's to highlight that `#IF` is evaluated at compile-time, rather than (in your example) after the previous call to `new Label`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: All of the code goes to the compiler at compile-time. In fact these directives are the only exception that will NOT be evaluated at compile-time, but before it.

Comment: I like the question though and would love to hear from an insider about the thought-process they went through when deciding this behavior.

Comment: I think this is configurable, I know at least my Visual Studio behaves differently depending on the solutions I open. Either way, the if-statements here are on the source code level, not on the code logic level, as such I think it is more logical that they're all the way out left.

Comment: I googled around, which indicated me that indent before #if is NOT allowed for C99. It is a convention, kept and used till today.

Comment: *When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.* - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: The C# IDE has lots and lots of formatting option, but not for this one.  Typing in # is enough to get it in the first column.  You can indent it by hand but as soon as the code gets auto-formatted it moves back again.  Which is the most basic reason why you always see it back in the 1st format, nobody particularly enjoys fighting the text editor.  Having it so visible is almost surely intended to make it obvious enough to avoid the problems it can cause while debugging.

Comment: @Ben "C99" is the C standard, not applicable to C#.

Comment: @HansPassant I would think that, but such an 'innormal' (forgive me if I were wrong) indent has been existed for years, they should be spotted and indented, but they are not. It must be some other reason I guess. :]

Comment: Indentation is often (not always, but often) associated with block level scoping (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx). Encouraging indentation might incorrectly imply that a block is involved, and thus variables declared inside the `#if` are scoped to that (non-existent) block. Not encouraging indentation makes it clear that no block is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Preprocessor_Directives) about preprocessor directives, the first option is preferred.

Still, the question remains open. Why does one's code editor avoid indentation before #if preprocessor directive? These may be the reasons:

**1)** - We use indentation in code in order to make it more readable. Indentations show us the structural blocks of related code. These blocks are nested one into other having a meaningful hierarchy.

```
class SomeClass {
    static void Func() {
        var Content = new Label();
        #if __IOS__
            Padding = new Thickness(1,2,3,4);
        #endif
    }
}
```

Have a look at the last indentation level before `Padding`. `var Content` line and `Padding` line are both is the same block. Doesn't it feel kind of misleading reducing readability?

**2)** - Now take a look at the following **valid** and **compilable** code:

```
// #define ABC
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if ABC
            Func();
        }

        static void Func() {
            Console.WriteLine("Will be printed if ABC is defined.");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to change the indentation? I think no, although nobody would probably write such code in the real life.

**3)** - We should better stick with conventions in order to better understand each other. That is why there so many standards all around us.

Answer (score 2):

The C# standard has this to say on the topic of preprocessor directives in this regard, [under section 2.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691094(v=vs.71).aspx):

> A preprocessing directive always occupies a separate line of source code and always begins with a # character and a preprocessing directive name. **White space may occur before the # character** and between the # character and the directive name.

*(my emphasis)*

As such there is no reason to use either over the other and this is thus left to personal style.

I will thus have to vote to close this question as "Primarily opinion-based".

Comment: It would be better if you add some source link in the answer

Comment: I had to hunt down a good link first, I took the paragraph out of my Annotated C# 4 Specification book.

Comment: Oh I see. Then the name of the book as a reference would be enough. Thanks for the link